# Automatically unzip files on SFTP server

Tags: python, php, automation, sftp, unzip

I need to find a way to automatically unlock & extract some zipped, password-protected files on an SFTP server whenever a zip file is dumped there. I know either Python or PHP would enable me to set up a script to unzip the files. However, I have the following questions:

- Is it possible to install Python or PHP on a standard SFTP server? (If not, are there any other options which can help in this case)? **EDIT:** If yes, what are the methods to install Python?
- Assuming I could get the script working on the server, is there a way to set that script to run automatically (either triggered when a
  file is added, or set to run every 15 minutes)?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is all possible. You can use Python scripted logic and CRON, etc. to schedule on Linux or Task Scheduler on Windows still running Python scripted language to do this for all application actions as you list. Use Python for this sort of task and not PHP though.... ***"automatically unlock & extract some zipped, password-protected files on an SFTP server whenever a zip file is dumped there"***

Comment: @ITSnuggles Thanks for your response. I just update the question - Can you give more details about _how_ I can install Python on there?

Comment: So are you working with Windows or Linux for scheduling the automated process to check for files, download, decrypt, etc? Install Python on what OS exactly?

Comment: @ITSnuggles Windows

Comment: Check here: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ to get the installer files for Windows and Python. Write your Python scripts, and then schedule them to run with [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx). Python has always seemed rather robust for the needs I've used it so it should be able to handle connecting to an FTP connection, checking for a file, download, decrypt, etc. although I'd personally use WinSCP and batch scripts with 7zip command line for the same process with Task Scheduler and a batch script, etc. for all actions.

Comment: There's nothing like *"standard SFTP server"*. What SFTP server is that? What platform? You wrote "Windows" above, but I'm not sure if that was referring to the server or your client machine.